# Visit all cells of a matrix with the least amount of steps

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given a matrix NxN which cells can have the following values:

- 0: free cell
- 1: obstacle cell
- 2: start/end (they are the same cell)

And the allowed movemnts are:

- up
- down
- right
- left

find one path from the star cell with the least amount of movements that visit all cells and return to the star.

Probably Branch and Bound or Backtracking would do the trick, but I'm working with quite big matrixes so it may be not the best solution.

I think Hamiltonian path is always the answer when it exists, am I right?

An example:

```
00000
01010
01120
00000
```

A possible solution would be: sdwwwaaswaasssdddw (take w as up, s as down, d as right and a as left)

Comment: So Hamiltonian path is a concept where u are provided with start and end node and you have to figure out a path where u visit all other available nodes.

Comment: ohh my bad so u have provided the start and end cell, got it, so it will be a hamiltonian cycle in ur case...

Comment: I think, I have a solution in mind, let me post it here. but the total time complexity of the algorithm with me O(N^2) because of the matrix, because i will be traversing through the matrix to create a graph, so that's why...

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, I wasn't expecting anything better than O(N^2)

Comment: Is it possible for you to post an example as well ?

Comment: Well, 2-approximation would be to build spanning tree and then traverse it.

Comment: spanning tree won't work since the starting point is also the end.